# Google Play Pre-Registration Sign Up number stuck

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

We opened the pre-registration for our app 2 weeks ago and we quickly received 136 sign ups but despite more people pre-registering the count hasn’t moved for almost 10 days.

Looked online but couldn’t find an answer anywhere.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ajnE.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking the community if anybody else have got the same problem that is the google play pre-registration sign up count stopped updating after reaching 136